# Implementation of Different custom 404 Page not found error pages based on routable sub-directories in NextJS (App Router Structure)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, app-router

I have a custom 404 error page (= not-found.tsx) file. Actually two, one within `app/(paths)` and one within `app/(paths)/(jobs)/jobs/(cats)`. The first not-found file should render when a user goes to url example `myapp.com/blablabla-nothing-here`. The second not-found file should render when a user goes to url example `myapp.com/jobs/blabla-no-job-cat-here`. In both these cases my custom not-found file does not render. Why? Here my full structure:

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqdN7.png)

P.S. The content of my `not-found` file is correct, because when I move it to `app/not-found` then it renders. The "global" one that is. The "local" inside /jobs does not.

Moving files around and expected it to work but it did not.

- [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs)
- [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript)
- [next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next.js)
- [next.js13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next.js13)

Answer (score 0):

You might get this solution useful:
Since, your root *not-found.tsx* file is working as desired, you need to go to your *job* directory and create a folder renaming it to **[...notFound]** then create a **page.txs** file inside it, and put your **not-found.tsx** codes inside this **page.tsx** file. then everything should work.

For exmaple, assuming your root `app/not-found.tsx` file contains the following codes:

```
// app/not-found.tsx
export default function NotFound(){
    // your code if needed.
    return(<p>Not found from root not-found.tsx</p>);
}
```

and your `app/job/not-found.tsx` file contains the following codes:

```
// app/job/not-found.tsx
export default function NotFound(){
    // your code if needed.
    return(<p>Not found from job not-found.tsx</p>);
}
```

move the codes in `app/job/not-found.tsx` to `app/job/[..notFound]/page.tsx` file accordingly:

```
// app/job/[...notFound]/page.tsx
export default function NotFound(){
    // your code if needed.
    return(<p>Not found from job not-found.tsx</p>);
}
```